# I am try to add add react-router-dom it does not let me

Tags: reactjs, api

I am try to add  add react-router-dom it does not let me.

here errors i get:

> PS D:\spring boot and react training> npm add react-router-dom
>
> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\spring
>   boot and react training\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\spring
>   boot and react training\package.json'
>
> npm WARN mini-create-react-context@0.4.0 requires a peer of
>   react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-router@5.2.0 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-router-dom@5.2.0 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN spring boot and react training No description
>
> npm WARN spring boot and react training No repository field.

```
adding a delete button in react, but it is not working when I click delete this error is shown in chrome console:  i can get data from server, not sure why delete does not work.

xhr.js:178 DELETE http://localhost:8080//users/getLoggedInUserName()%20%7B%20%20%20%20let%20user%20=%20sessionStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser');%20%20%20%20if%20(user%20===%20null)%20return%20'';%20%20%20%20return%20user;%20%20%7D/todos/1 500
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:76
wrap @ bind.js:9
deleteTodo @ TodoDataService.js:15
deleteTodoClicked @ ListTodoComponent.jsx:60
onClick @ ListTodoComponent.jsx:102
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61) 



here is api:

deleteTodo(name, id){

       return Axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080//users/${name}/todos/${id}`)

    }

here is my function:




deleteTodoClicked(id){

        let username=AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName

        TodoDataService.deleteTodo(username, id)


       .then(
           response =>{
               this.setState({message : `Delete todos ${id} successful`})
              // this.refreshTodos()
           }
       )
    }

on server side console I see this:


2020-05-25 23:28:04.828  WARN 15868 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Missing URI template variable 'useranme' for method parameter of type String]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install peer dependencies first(manually).

```
npm install --save-dev <peer-dependency>
```

Then,`npm install --save react-router-dom` solves the issue. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do `npm init` then `npm install react-router-dom`

You need to setup up a package json first, which npm init does auto for you https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

Answer (score 0):

In order to install `react-router-dom` via npm you must use `install`

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

with yarn you will use the add command

```
yarn add react-router-dom
```

Seems like you mixed up the commands